# How do I calculate this logarithmic expression?

Tags: logarithms

What I'm not sure about is the power of two above the logarithm. I just wanted to verify I'm calculating correctly

Do I do these steps...?

1 - Take absolute value of variable AL

2 - Take log base 10 of result 1

3 - take result 2 squared

4 - take result 3 multiply by variable b2

[image: expression]

Comment: Yes. Ps you can't take logs of negative numbers anyway :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. $\log^2x$ is short for $(\log x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Your solution is $b_2(\mathrm{\log}_{10 }|AL|)^2$.